# Want white space inbetween images in a responsive webpage?

Tags: html, css, responsive, fluid-layout

Here is a screenshot of what I am working on:

[image: screenshot]

Now the thing is I would like some white space in-between the images so they are a little bit spaced out and I have tried adding `style="margin-right:25px"` to the first three images however if I do this they become slightly bigger and the last image stays small:

[image: example here]

My current HTML for this page is

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="lower"><img src="images/one.jpg" alt="Ring being put on finger"/></div>
    <div class="lower"><img src="images/two.jpg" alt="The mens trousers"/></div>
    <div class="lower"><img src="images/three.jpg" alt="Flowers"/></div>
    <div class="lower"><img src="images/four.jpg" alt="The rings"/></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
#footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.lower {
  display: table-cell;
}

#footer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 256px;
}
```

Please bear in mind that this is a responsive webpage not static.

Thankyou

Comment: Any particular reason you do that using table-cell display?

Comment: table-cell display is so the images resize according to the width of the device. found a link before on codepen for it but cant remember the link now

Comment: for images resizing according to width of a device you should use:
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
in your <head> tags

Comment: at the moment all my images are resizing its just this last issue with the images having to be positioned in a horizontal line

Comment: Could you paste your code on some jsfiddle? You made me curious :)

Comment: I can but  I cant give you the images as its a project for college and I would ask my tutor but his not online at the moment.

Comment: OK, no worries, just send me the code so I can take a look with whatever placeholder images ;).

Comment: Take a read at this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

`display: flex` property is what you need for this type of layouts

P.S: you can find many other articles if you search on google

Comment: The code is on https://jsfiddle.net/n47L3s5o/ The image i use in the header is 1024 x 192 px The main image is 6204 x 2004 px and the four image on the bottom are 230 x 196. also on the file there was an added boilerplate.css as im using dreamweaver to do this

Comment: the four images at the bottom are 256 wide not 230, sry

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.lower {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.lower:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but on bigger screens there is still withe space to the right of the last image and then on smaller screens the last image moves down to a new line.

Comment: Also, u probably should add font-size: 0 in #footer, as it adds one white space when u hit enter in between lines of your code and can cause your last image to not fit in images row.

Comment: Are all the images same size?

Comment: yes, and thank you for helping me

Comment: Finally got an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281659/how-to-force-space-inbetween-a-css-table-responsive-webpage/40281796?noredirect=1#comment67822094_40281796

Comment: Good one, but I am pretty sure you can avoid using flex in this case. Also, make sure to check browser support for that solution. Will take a look on your example after work and let you know here what I figured out ;).

Comment: Thanks and I don't know who said the flex answer was useful, that's just causing more problems, its the answer with the tick that I used.

Comment: just in-case your wondering how I fixed it I have added a jsfiddle file, and then under the media tags in css I changed the padding in the .lower class to alter the width of the space depending on device size. I would also like to know your solution - https://jsfiddle.net/67425xta/

Comment: OK, will take a good look on that at home and will let you know :)