# How to force space inbetween a css table (responsive webpage)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, css-tables

I have a CSS table and I would like to have space in-between the cells but not at the left of the first image and the right of the last image.

Here is a screenshot of what I have:

[image: current]
Here is a screenshot of what I would like:

[image: want]

The current HTML is:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="lower"><img src="images/one.jpg" alt="Ring being put on finger"/></div>
        <div class="lower"><img src="images/two.jpg" alt="The mens trousers"/></div>
        <div class="lower"><img src="images/three.jpg" alt="Flowers"/></div>
        <div class="lower"><img src="images/four.jpg" alt="The rings"/></div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS is

```
#footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.lower {
  display: table-cell;
}

#footer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 256px;
}
```

Please bear in mind that this is a responsive webpage so I would like the space to always remain however I would like the space to change according to device size, so using %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hi pls apply this css and set padding 

.lower {
display: table-cell;
padding:0 20px;
}
.lower:first-child{ padding-left:0}
.lower:last-child{ padding-right:0}
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, edited it a little bit and the only thing i had to do was use media tags to set the padding px so the size changes depending on device size, I was asking for % but this solution also works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apply this.

```
#footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    background-color: #F00;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: content-height;
}

.lower {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#footer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/QKPRmV)

Comment: now the last image is bigger than all the other images?

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you'll have to adjust the `#footer` as well, updated my answer.

Comment: This results in padding below the first 3 images, and the last image is fine, I tried to add padding-bottom 0; but that does not work

Comment: I've updated it once again, this time re-writing the majority of your current code. Could you check if the current codepen is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: flex;` instead of `display: table;`

Give `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to the parent.

Comment: I have researched using flex and the space-between element really only applies to smaller sized images.

Comment: you are not using directly image as child right so it will work give **text-align: center;** to the child div element. It will solve if it has any size variations in the images.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS adjacent element selector:

```
.lower + .lower {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```css
#footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
.lower {
  display: table-cell;
}
.lower + .lower {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#footer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="lower"><img src="images/one.jpg" alt="Ring being put on finger"/></div>
  <div class="lower"><img src="images/two.jpg" alt="The mens trousers"/></div>
  <div class="lower"><img src="images/three.jpg" alt="Flowers"/></div>
  <div class="lower"><img src="images/four.jpg" alt="The rings"/></div>
</div>
```